# In Karaf's feature.xml, is it possible to add a repo?

Tags: cxf, karaf

I am wanting to have the equivalent of this karaf command:

```
feature:add-repo mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.3.1/xml/features
```

The bigger picture is that I want to be able to have a clean karaf install, copy a .kar file to the deploy folder, and have it download and install all of the features defined in feature.xml.

Currently, I have a feature.xml that lists the required features, but cxf is not in the pre-configured repos.  For my testing, I have added the repo to `org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`.

I tried using the `<library>` element, but that doesn't appear to do this.

(My work is based on the [karaf-jpa-example](https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/master/examples/karaf-jpa-example).)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you are trying to do, this should do the trick:

```
<features name="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}"
    xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0">

    <repository>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.3.1/xml/features</repository>

    <feature name="your-feature" version="${project.version}">
        ...
    </feature>
```

See the [CXF Karaf feature project](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/osgi/karaf/features/src/main/resources/features.xml) for a rich set of examples.